# nodejs: Cannot find module 'passport'

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, passport.js

I am missing something fairly basic at the beginning of my exploration into Node.js. I am trying to build a little app using passportjs authentication.

I have the following line in my `app.ts`:

```
import passport = require("passport");
```

and the following im my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "ftct",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "ftct",
    "main": "app.js",
    "author":
    {
        "name": "Mark.Norgate",
        "email": ""
    },
    "dependencies":
    {
        "express": "3.4.4",
        "jade": "*",
        "passport": "^0.3.2",
        "stylus": "*"
    }
}
```

However, Visual Studio 2015 complains:

```
Build: Cannot find module 'passport'.
```

What am I missing? I have read a little of the documentation for passportjs but nothing so far that indicates what the problem might be.

Comment: Try ```var passport = require('passport')```

Comment: @nickdbush Makes no difference

Comment: Did you do a `npm install`?

Comment: Are you using NTVS?  (Node Tools for Visual Studio)

Comment: @JaredDykstra Yes I am...

Comment: When using NTVS, Visual Studio should automatically run `npm install` if you've edited package.json in the IDE, so unless you used a different editor, it's probably not the answer provided by @Matt

Comment: I'd already guessed that. With my minimal understanding of node I think it's all configured correctly. But obviously it isn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
import passport = require("passport");
```

to:

```
var passport = require("passport");
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding a new module to your package.json won't actually include the dependency in the repository. You'll need to either run `npm install` after adding dependencies to package.json, or you can install packages using something like `npm install <package name>`. In this case, you'd want `npm install passport`.

`npm install` will download the source from npm and put it into the ./node_modules directory.

[npm install documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I'd already run 'npm install passport'. It's there in my node_modules folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where passport was installed and properly saved in package.json but was still getting an error.

My issue was that within package.json there were the lines

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.1"
  },
```

I compared my package.json to other examples online and then removed that line and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Remove node_modules, remove package-lock.json, then run npm install and then run npm install --save passport.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and did the above examples, but I just solved it only by changing the version of the passport, now I don't know why, but with version 0.4.1 my application didn't work (even requiring the module and not using it), and to solve it, I just ran the following command  `npm install passport@0.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

install package types like :

```
npm install @types/passport
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to leave this here since some guides/tutorials tend to forget to mention that passport-local or any of their other co-dependencies are just co-dependencies which means that the other packages depend on passport to be installed as well, therefore make sure that you actually have passport installed, see installation command bellow.

```
npm i passport
```

Then you can simply run

```
import passport from "passport"
```